# Why do elements with min-height set collapse in IE11?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a layout together that works in both Internet Explorer and Firefox. I'm running into a few issues in both browsers, but the big one right now is div height.

I have a fixed div at the top that's 92px tall. The page is made up of multiple divs. The first div needs to be 100vh tall. I have padding set to compensate for the first fixed div. The other divs should be 100vh - 92px tall.

In Firefox, this works fine. In Internet Explorer 11, the divs are collapsed. Some divs may have only a little bit of text, which is why they need a min-height. If they have a lot of text, they need to stretch to fit the content.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fixeddiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 92px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red
}

.firstdiv {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 92px;
}

.otherdiv1 {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 75px);
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.otherdiv2 {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 75px);
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixeddiv"></div>
<div class="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="otherdiv1"></div>
<div class="otherdiv2"></div>
```

Comment: if you are searching to see if you can use somehting on broswer https://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: @FrancescoFortin I wasn't. But according to that, it looks like I should be able to use min-height in IE.

Comment: Does IE support 'calc' for CSS? I'm not sure.

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't need to set `width: 100%` on all your divs. They are by default. If you do, something's wrong with your layout as a whole.

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 100vh` on `html, body`.

Comment: Your snippet works fine in IE11 for me.